# How to check if a record is new in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I recently started using Eloquent.

When I used PHP Active Record, there was a nice function that checked if a record was loaded from the database or is a new instance. Is there something similar in Eloquent that I could use?

By new I mean:

```php
$article = new Article;
```

whereas one from the database would be

```php
$article = Article::find(1);
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

All laravel models have a `->exists` property.

More specifically if the model is either loaded from the database, or has been saved to the database since being created the `exists` property will be true; Otherwise it will be false.

If you wish to know if the model has been modified since being grabbed from the database, or simply not saved at all (aka if it needs saving) then you can use the `->isDirty()` function.

The Laravel API is a useful place for this kind of information:
http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_isDirty
 and often sheds far more light than the default documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, Laravel's documentation barely scratches the surface of the framework.

Comment: Not to confuse with method `$model->exists()` which does something else, like counts rows in database, and returns if count > 0 :)

Answer (score 107):

Your model object has an attribute exactly designed for that. It's wasRecentlyCreated :

```
$item = Item::firstOrCreate(['title' => 'Example Item']);

if ($item->wasRecentlyCreated === true) {
    // item wasn't found and have been created in the database
} else {
    // item was found and returned from the database
}
```

For more clarification between the way exists variable works vs wasRecentlyCreated variable (copied from the comment by CJ Dennis below)

```
 /* Creating a model */ 
 $my_model = new MyModel; 
 $my_model->exists === false; 
 $my_model->wasRecentlyCreated === false; 
 $my_model->save(); 
 $my_model->exists === true; 
 $my_model->wasRecentlyCreated === true;
```

As opposed to if a model was loaded from a previous request:

```
/* Loading a Model */ 
$my_model = MyModel::first(); 
$my_model->exists === true; 
$my_model->wasRecentlyCreated === false;
```

Comment: `wasRecentlyCreated ` indicates if the model was inserted during the current request lifecycle. So even if the record was missing from the DB, it will only return `true` after it is saved.

Comment: `/* Creating a model */
$my_model = new MyModel;
$my_model->exists === false;
$my_model->wasRecentlyCreated === false;
$my_model->save();
$my_model->exists === true;
$my_model->wasRecentlyCreated === true;

/* Loading a Model */
$my_model = MyModel::first();
$my_model->exists === true;
$my_model->wasRecentlyCreated === false;`

Comment: It returns `false` if you create a record then query again for that newly created `Item::firstOrCreate(['title' => 'Example Item']);`
then,
`Item::where(['title' => 'Example Item'])->first()->wasRecentlyCreated` this will return `false`. Remember to get the return value of the create methods. But the problems is, when working with creating related models and querying the newly created models.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `$appends` on model if you will use it many times.. for example to check if the newly created comment is edited after created.

```
class Comment extends Model
{
     protected $appends = ['is_edited'];

     public function getIsEditedAttribute()
     {
          return $this->attributes['is_edited'] = ($this->created_at != $this->updated_at) ? true : false;
     }
}
```

You can use it like

```
$comment = Comment::findOrFail(1);

if($comment->is_edited){
      // write your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel if a record is newly created and has not been updated before, the created_at and the updated_at will be the same

```
if($article->created_at == $article->updated_at) {
   // Logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$article = new Article;
var_dump($article->id); == null

$article = Article::find(1);
var_dump($article->id); == string(1) "1"
```

so

```
if ($article->id) {
     // I am existing
} else {
    // I am new
}
```

Comment: While maybe not ideal, circa 2013 I feel like this is an ok answer.

Answer (score -4):

I am using Laravel Eloquent's [updateOrCreate()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Pivot.html#method_updateOrCreate) method to create or update records when importing from a CSV file.

```
$product = $this->updateOrCreate($attributes, $values);
```

I wanted to count the amount of newly created records and updated records. Since the `updateOrCreate()` method saves the record to the database upon creation, `$product->exists` will always return `true`.

An alternative is to compare the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps of the model with the current time:

```
if($product->created_at == Carbon::now())
            $created++;
        elseif ($product->updated_at == Carbon::now())
            $updated++;
```

Comment: If in the same request, then the timestamp lacks enough precision to know if the record was just created