# What does isDirty() mean in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

First of all, I am not familiar with Laravel so much (or with the term "dirty" for that matter).
I stumbled upon this line of code -

```php
if ($this->isDirty('status')) {
    if (Notification::has('website-status-' . strtolower($this->status))) {
        Notification::set($this->account, 'website-status-' . strtolower($this->status), $this->emailAttributes())
            ->email();
    }
}
```

And I couldn't understand what that means exactly. I tried to find out on the internet but the Laravel site only says this

> "Determine if a given attribute is dirty"

which doesn't really help...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498518/how-to-check-if-a-record-is-new-in-laravel  "If you wish to know if the model has been modified since being grabbed from the database, or simply not saved at all (aka if it needs saving) then you can use the ->isDirty() function"

Comment: When a record is fetched from the database, it is 'clean'. After you modify it, it becomes 'dirty'.  Once you save it back to the database, it becomes 'clean' again.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When you want to know if the model has been edited since it was queried from the database, or isn't saved at all, then you use the `->isDirty()` function.

Comment: You just copy/pasted `ka_lins` comment almost word for word without acknowledgment?

Comment: @Adam he doesn't have to, [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288849/5581565)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/r7sxgq

Any idea this method returning me TRUE but it's not changes any single value I think.

Comment: @MAmirShahzad what returns when you call ->getChanges()?

I got weird behaviour when save  decimal(8,2) values on database. (type casting detect as changes).

To solve this I use number_format($variable, 2, '.', '')

Answer (score 28):

The isDirty method determines if any attributes have been changed since the model was loaded. You may pass a specific attribute name to determine if a particular attribute is dirty.

```
    $user = User::create([
        'first_name' => 'Amir',
        'last_name' => 'Kaftari',
        'title' => 'Developer',
    ]);

    $user->title = 'Jafar';
    $user->isDirty(); // true
    $user->isDirty('title'); // true
    $user->isDirty('first_name'); // false
```

Answer (score 14):

Eloquent provides the `isDirty`, `isClean`, and `wasChanged` methods to examine the internal state of your model and determine how its attributes have changed from when they were originally loaded.

You can find complete description and examples of these three methods here in the official document:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes

Comment: This is the only answer that point to official documentation. Must be selected as accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

As support for the accepted answer:

```
$model = Model::find(1);

$model->first_column = $request->first_value;
$model->second_column = $request->second_value;
$model->third_column = $request->third_value;

if($model->isDirty()){
// the model has been edited, else codes here will not be executed
}

$model->save();
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code does? How does it "support" the other answer?

Comment: I converted his sentence into a (sample) code to get a picture of the whole scenario for future reference since OP's code was just a bare bone.

Comment: Kinda weird. I would expect that if it returns true, then execute the code because it's in fact dirty.

Comment: Its funny my suggested edit was overridden by @kapitan. the thing is why would you want to ```$model->save()``` every single time when there is an `if()` above which clearly identifies the case when you want to `save()` and when you avoid calling `save()`. To summerise my concern "You should save if and only if when `$model->isDirty()` evaluates to `true`". Please do correct me here I am missing something.

Comment: @SalmanMalik - first,if you wont use a package,that is where you can put your audit trail routine.second,you dont need to manually check if it's dirty or not to have the `save()` method,because laravel CAN do that for you out of the box.if youll observe,the `updated_at` field on your database wont be updated if you didnt edit anything even though you clicked the update button on your form.third,including the `save()` inside the `isDirty()` condition isnt the answer the OP is looking for.thank you very much for showing interest to edit my answer!

Comment: @kapitan this is exactly what I am saying. Why `$model->save()` outside the `if()` block when it is obvious that it will only make a difference when the model `isDirty` or else it is just an additional statement which does nothing but execute.

Comment: @SalmanMalik - the `if($model->isDirty()){}` condition was added here for the sake of answering the OP's question.just imagine the whole code without it on normal situation.which means that the `save()` really doesn't need to be inside it.because it's like it has its own `isDirty()` routine under the hood.thank you brother.

Comment: @kapitan it doesn't answer OP's question. You're welcome.

Comment: @SalmanMalik -  if that's what you think, i would suggest that you create your own answer then. thank you.