# If value exist in database don't save Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm creating a wishlist where the user can save his own products and save them. What I want is that a user can't save a product more than one time.
So, what I'm doing is, if the product_id exists in the DB, I don't want to save the new record.

**This is my code, what am I doing wrong?**

```
public function addWishlist(Wishlist $wishlist) {        
    $wishlist->user_id = request('user_id');
    $wishlist->product_id = request('product_id');

    if(DB::table('wishlists')->where('product_id' !== $wishlist->product_id)) {
        $wishlist->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's already an eloquent function for that `updateOrCreate`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

Comment: use firstOrCreate and then check for wasRecentlyCreated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498518/how-to-check-if-a-record-is-new-in-laravel

Comment: `where('product_id' !== $wishlist->product_id)` -- what do you expect from this conditon? It will select all items from `wishlists`with the condition `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this

```
public function addWishlist(Wishlist $wishlist) {  
    $userId = request('user_id');
    $productId = request('product_id');

    $found = Wishlist::where('user_id', $userId)->where('product_id', $productId)->count();

    if($found == 0) {
        $wishlist->user_id = $userId;
        $wishlist->product_id = $productId;
        $wishlist->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it would be a mess change my code for calling this function.

Comment: @danhergir i updated my answer, you can make these changes in your code. it should work

Comment: You did it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addWishlist(Wishlist $wishlist) {   

    if(DB::table('wishlists')->where(['user_id'=>$user_id,'product_id'=>$wishlist->product_id])->exists()){
         // record already exist 
         return redirect()->back();
    }else{
         // record not exist , save the record
         $withlist = new Wishlist();     
         $wishlist->user_id = request('user_id');
         $wishlist->product_id = request('product_id');
         $wishlist->save();
         return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but it keeps saving the record if the value of the product_id is saved in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `firstOrNew` and you need to check with `user_id` and `product_id` combination

```
    $wishlist::firstOrNew(array('user_id' => request('user_id'),'product_id'=>request('product_id')));
    $wishlist->user_id = request('user_id');
    $wishlist->product_id = request('product_id');
    $wishlist->save();
    return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: It isn't working correctly. It's saving the record if the product_id is repeated. So, I'm having the same problem

Comment: Did you noticed this line `you need to check with user_id and product_id combination` ? @danhergir

Comment: I only need to check the product_id. I changed your code, but it's not working anyway

Comment: if your not check with user id means .if A user choose one product means . B user can't choose that product . is it okay ? @danhergir

Comment: No, what I mean is if a user added that product to the wishlist, that user can't do it again.

Comment: I can understood your point . if `user A` added `product_id` 1 .Now `user B` trying to add that the same `product_id` 1 . now you can't insert because that `product_id` 1 already exists in table that's why i'm telling you need to check with combination column `user_id` and `product_id`

Comment: use firstOrCreate and then check for wasRecentlyCreated  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498518/how-to-check-if-a-record-is-new-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried firstOrCreate()

```
 $user = User::firstOrCreate(['email' => $email])
```